# How to filter after the fourth number in a series of numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to filter entire F column which contains number in format:
**1005991860040**
I want to filter after the fourth number and to get entire row with next 3 numbers.

Examples:
I want to be able to assign those 3 numbers.
If I sign for example 991 I want to get all rows which that contains column F with a given criterion.

Column F:

**1005991860040**
**2006991860040**
**1207991860040**
**0109911860040**
**1005992860040**
**2006992860040**
**1207992860040**

Result:

```
1.  Row A|B|C|D|E|F(1005991860040)  
22. Row A|B|C|D|E|F(2006991860040)  
65. Row A|B|C|D|E|F(1207991860040)
```

Can't display as in excel, but I hope you understand me.

Comment: I'd add a helper column `=MID(A2,5,LEN(A2)-4)` and then you can sort/filter on that column numerically.

Comment: I solved with =MID(F2,5,LEN(F2)-10) . Thank you.

Comment: If that solves your problem, then post it as an answer (you can answer your own question) so people know this is solved.